# why ssh local forwarding of ssh traffic does not work?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote ssh server at remote.com. On my local host, I forward all the ssh traffic to it:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:88:remote.com:22 user@remote.com
```

Now, when I do the following, ssh just hangs:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 88
```

I thought traffic to 127.0.0.1:88 is forwarded to remote.com:22. Why does it hang?

Comment: Are you running first ssh command from `root` user? If not, were there a message that port `88` couldn't be bound?

Comment: (1) Is there a message `cannot listen to port: 88`? (2) `remote.com` in `127.0.0.1:88:remote.com:22` is resolved on the server. Are you sure the server resolves `remote.com` to itself? Why not trying `127.0.0.1` in the first place?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it is normal if server resolves its name to itself, this is not a error :) There is another curiosity, as this: why to connect to server via SSH and tunnel some local port to the same SSH port you're already connected to? What is the purpose of this construction?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Normal is not equivalent to "a must".

Comment: Yes, there was a message that the port could not be bound!! After fixing that, the problem went away.